# C Stack pointing to Address?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I am new to C. I have implemented a simple stack with some structs and what not. I have posted the entire code below. The problem section is commented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
typedef struct Stack{
    Node *top;
    int size;
} Stack;

/* Function Prototypes */
void push(Stack *sPtr, int data);
int pop(Stack *sPtr);
void create(Stack *sPtr);

int main(void)
{
    static Stack first;
    create(&first);

    push(&first,4);
    push(&first,3);
    push(&first,2);

    printf("%d\n",pop(&first));
    printf("%d\n",pop(&first));
    printf("%d\n",pop(&first));
    exit(1); 
}

void push(Stack *sPtr, int data)
{
    struct Node newNode;
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.next = sPtr->top;
    sPtr->top = &newNode;
    sPtr->size++;
    printf("%d\n",sPtr->top->data);
}
int pop(Stack *sPtr)
{
    struct Node *returnNode = sPtr->top;
    struct Node *topNode = sPtr->top;
    if(sPtr->size != 0){
        sPtr->top = topNode->next; /* =============PROBLEM?=============== */
        return returnNode->data;
    }
    else{
        printf("Error: Stack is Empty!\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
void create(Stack *sPtr)
{
    sPtr->size = 0;
    sPtr->top = NULL;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
4
3
2
2
8103136
680997
```

So obviously, it is pulling off the top node, and then **printing the addresses of the next two nodes, instead of their data.**

But why is it doing this? As far as I know (which is little) preforming this operation

```
sPtr->top = topNode->next;
```

should tell the program to make `top` now point to to `topNode.next`. But instead, it seems to be returning the address. What's going on here?

Comment: `pop()` never decrements the `size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `push()` function, you're creating a new `struct Node` and adding it to your stack. However, the node is a local variable within the scope of `push()`--allocated on the stack (not your stack, the call stack), and will be gone when `push()` returns.

What you want to do is create the node on the **heap**, which means it will still be there after `push()` returns.

Since you're coding in C, you'll want to do something like:

```
struct Node *newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Since you're now dealing with heap-allocated memory, you'll need to make sure that at some point it gets freed (somewhere) using `free()`.

You're also not decrementing `size` as Jonathan has pointed out.

Comment: Well spotted; I wasn't even looking at `push()` since there was clearly a problem in `pop()` at about the identified point.  It just goes to show that where's there's one bug, there's usually more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading up a bit on `malloc` and `free`, I think I have a better understanding of it now.

Answer (score 3):

One trouble is that `pop()` never decrements `size`, so `size` is really 'number of elements ever pushed onto stack', not 'the number of elements in the current stack'.

```
int pop(Stack *sPtr)
{
    struct Node *returnNode = sPtr->top;
    struct Node *topNode = sPtr->top;
    if (sPtr->size != 0)
    {
        sPtr->top = topNode->next;
        sPtr->size--;
        return returnNode->data;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Stack is Empty!\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Another trouble, as pointed out by [unluddite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198164/unluddite) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735618/15168) is that you are not pushing data correctly. You need both fixes to be safe.  There might still be other problems (such as not freeing memory correctly — or at all), but these two will get you a long way.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the catch! It seems that the memory allocation was the primary error. If I could accept two, I'd bump yours too!